# bibliography rendering "Pp." instead of "pp." for page numbers

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

My .bib file contains the following entry:

```
@incollection{test,
  author = "Ove Grandstrand",
  title       = "Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights",
  editor      = "Jan Fagerberg and David C. Mowery and Richard R. Nelson",
  booktitle   = "The Oxford Handbook of Innovation",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2004,
  pages       = "266-290",
  chapter     = 10,
}
```

When I compile with latex and bibtex and the natbib package using the humannat style, I get the following rendering:

> Grandstrand, O.
>   2004. Innovation and intellectual property rights. In *The Oxford Handbook of Innovation*, J. Fagerberg, D. C. Mowery, and R. R. Nelson, eds., chapter 10, Pp. 266–290. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Of course, "Pp." is wrong: the first p shouldn't be capitalized. What's going wrong here?

Update:

Here's the latex file I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

 \begin{document}

Here are some natbib examples. You can cite examples using the citation key \citep{bar} in your .bib file. There are commands for in-text citations, like \citet{bar}. And you can pass an option to specify additional details, such as a page or chapter number, as an option \citep[p. 130]{bar}. For another example, see \cite{test}.

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{humannat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DaiBowen: I've added the latex code.

Comment: Are you open to using biblatex instead? Offtopic: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so the former is sufficient. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded last, and you're loading `geometry` twice.

Comment: @Troy: I'm pulling a recycled headed from old files I've used, so I didn't scrutinize for redundancies. I'd prefer to solve this problem rather than switch to biblatex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the way that `humannat.bst` was defined. See sample `humannat` references [here](https://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/humannat.pdf), and note that it uses `Pp.` by default. You need to modify the style file manually if you want to change it to `pp`. If you're bent on using `Bibtex`:

1. Download the `humannat.bst` file from CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/humannat.bst).
2. Open it up with your editor, search for `Pp.` You should see a line that says `{ "Pp.~" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }`.
3. Change the `"Pp.~"` to `"pp."`, as well as the `"P.~"` in the line below it to `"p."`. (i.e. Remove the `~` and change the capitalization of the P's.)
4. Save the `.bst` file as a copy under a new name (say, `humannatpp.bst`).
5. Place the `.bst` file in the same directory as your main `.tex` file.
6. Compile with Bibtex etc. and you're done.

[image: bst]

Comment: For good form -- and, more importantly, for adherence to software licensing stipulations! -- you should instruct the OP make a *copy* of `humannat.bst`, to give the copy a new name (say, `humannatpp.bst`), and to only edit the copy -- *not* the file `humannat.bst` itself. Incidentally, I think the `~` ("tie") after "Pp." (or "pp.") is an *error*: it ought to be "pp." (without the `~`). And, while you're at it recommending changing "Pp." to "pp.", you might as well recommend changing "P." to "p." in the next line of the bst file.

Comment: @Mico made the edits, thanks. :) I don't get why the `~` is an error. Does that function as a `non-line breaker`?

Comment: Thanks. I thought this couldn't possibly have been by design, so I didn't even check the documentation.

Comment: Do check out the contents of the function `tie.or.space.connect`: It inserts a space token as well. Having two consecutive space tokens, which creates an interword space that's twice as wide as all others, looks rather ugly.